# How to show the function $f\colon z\mapsto\lvert z\rvert^2$ is continuous on the entire complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I am required to show this using the epsilon-delta definition of continuity and I'm having trouble applying what I know about real functions to complex ones.
I've let $z_0$ be a complex number in $\mathbb{C}$ and then considered all points in the open-disc $D(z_0,1):=\lbrace z:\lvert z-z_0\rvert<1\rbrace$.
I know that $\lvert f(z)-f(z_0)\rvert={\large\lvert}\lvert z\rvert^2-\lvert z_0\rvert^2{\large\lvert}$ but I'm not sure how I can relate this to $\lvert z-z_0\rvert<1$.
Is difference of two squares the method required?

Comment: Just think of it as a real valued function of two variables: $(x,y) \to x^2 + y^2$. And please [edit] the question to use mathjax formatting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I don't understand how that helps solve the problem.

Comment: Why is $|f(z)-f(z_0)|=|z|^2-|z_0|^2$?

Comment: @Anteater23 That function of two variables is precisely the function whose continuity you want to prove. You could also carefully read a proof of the continuity of $x \to x^2$ in the one variable case and see how to apply it almost verbatim to the complex case.

Comment: Thank you michael, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

For any sequence $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $z_n \stackrel{n  \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} z_0$ you have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left| |z_n|^2 - |z_0|^2\right|& = & \left| (|z_n| - |z_0|)(|z_n| + |z_0|)\right| \\
& = &  \left| |z_n| - |z_0|\right|\cdot\left(|z_n| + |z_0|\right) \\
& \leq & \left| z_n - z_0\right|\cdot \left(|z_n| + |z_0|\right) \\
& \stackrel{n  \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} & 0\cdot 2|z_0| = 0 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

So $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to rewrite the original function $f(z) = |z|^{2}$ as $f(z) = z z^{*}$ where $z^{*}$ is the complex conjugacy.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z = x+\mathrm{i}y$ and $\delta = \delta_x + \mathrm{i} \delta_y$.  Then \begin{align*}
|z+\delta| &= |(x+\delta_x) + \mathrm{i}(y +\delta_y)|  \\
    &\leq |x+\delta_x| + |y +\delta_y|  \text{.}
\end{align*}

With a little triangle inequality manipulation, you can get the inequality you need.